# line after text is entered - inputs styled like materialize

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good Day,

I'm working on a form where the inputs are styled like materialize. In my form the input has no border, but I am using a separate div (given the class of 'border') as the line beneath the text. I have been successful in changing the color and height of the border class when the user enters the field. What I would like to do is have the line change back to it's original color after the users exits the input field (working) and, if there is text in the field keep the height so the border appears thicker than that of an empty field. Here is a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2h9dfbc/125/)**. I was able to work out a solution for the select box. The effect there is exactly what I want to accomplish with the other inputs.

I've tried a couple of iterations of event listeners and some change functions. These have resulted in either no success or the application of the thicker boarder to all inputs whether there is value or not.

This gives every div with the border class a height of 2px after clicking/tabbing out of the first field

```
$('.targetField').change(function() {
  if ($(".targetField").val() != "") {
    $(this).next('.border').css('height', '2px');
  }
});
```

Same with this, even though I am targeting a specific id (I get why, it's broadly targeting any .border)

```
$('#fname').click(function(){
 var currentVal = $(this).val();
  if (currentVal == "") {
       $('.border').css('height', '2px');
         }
    });
```

Finally, my event listener attempt, which doesn't seem to fire:

```
$('.targetField').focus(function() {
  $(this).next('.border').addClass('active');
});
$('.targetField').focusout(function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  if (currentVal == "") {
    $(this).next('.border').removeClass('active');
    $(this).next('.border').css('height', '1px'); //original param
  } else {
    $(this).next('.border').removeClass('active');
    $(this).next('.border').css('height', '2px'); //param from the class you want to keep
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood exactly what style you wanted to change but this should be a good place to start.

You don't need any javascript, it's possible with pure CSS and a placeholder attribute on the input. I got it working in the fiddle by removing all of the javascript and using a ":not(placeholder-shown)" selector in addition to your existing rules.

Placeholder with a space for the input:

```
  <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder=" " name="fname" class="targetField">
```

Style for the line on the before element:

```
.rec-box .mat-input-outer input:not(:placeholder-shown)~.border::before,
.rec-box .mat-input-outer textarea:not(:placeholder-shown)~.border::before {
  width: 100%;
  background: #2B6FD7;
  height: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this a go. That's not quite what I was trying to accomplish. The blue active state is good to go. In the fiddle, use the select box to pick a state. Once you move to the next field the line under the select stays at a 2px height. That's what I'm looking to do with the other fields.

Comment: You can add whatever styles you want to the selector and they'll show only if the user has entered text. I adjusted it to show you how.

Comment: The rest of the code I showed was to let you know that you don't need to use javascript to create active classes for inputs -- that's what the :focus selector is already accomplishing.

Comment: I follow what you're saying now. This makes tons more sense to use then a js solution.

Comment: Great! Yeah, CSS has a surprising amount of helpful selectors. I'd always recommend giving them a try before turning to js.